# Url rewriting for all identical filenames

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I would like to rewrite all my URL's like so:

`http://example.com/folder/40/name/test.php`
and
`http://example.com/folder/40/test.php`

to

`http://example.com/test.php`

Does anyone have a solution?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by using htaccess.  It will redirect all urls like

```
http://example.com/folder/40/name/test.php
http://example.com/folder/40/test.php
```

to

```
http://example.com/test.php
```

In the htaccess file add below lines

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(img|anyother folders that you want to ignore|anyother folders that you want to ignore|...)
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/test.php$ test.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(img|anyother folders that you want to ignore|anyother folders that you want to ignore|...)
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/test.php$ test.php [L]
```

more information [Htaccess Rewrites](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/modrewrite-tips-tricks.html)